# Qt: Position pos() of Child Item not updated when parent is moved

Tags: c++, qt

When I drag the parent Item on the scene, the parent's position is updated properly (by overriding itemChange()) and the Child Item also moves but when I do qDebug() << childItem.pos(), it still shows the first value it was initialised with. (also overrode the child obj's itemChange() fn). What am I doing wrong? Kindly guide me.

Rough Code:

Parent's itemChange()

```
if (change == ItemPositionChange && scene()) {
    QPointF newPos = value.toPointF();
    return newPos;
} 

else
    return QGraphicsItem::itemChange(change, value);
}
```

The "change == ItemPositionChange" returns false for child Item.

Comment: Did you enable the flag "ItemSendsGeometryChanges" for your graphics item?

Comment: Yes I did......

Comment: [QGraphicsItem::Pos](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#pos) "Returns the position of the item in parent coordinates" and that hasn't changed --  so I wouldn't expect there to be any such notification.  What you're seeing is exactly what I would expect.

Comment: Do you mean to say that in parent's coordinate system, relative to parent, the child's position hasn't changed, thus shows the first initialised pos?

Comment: Yes.  That's my understanding.

Comment: Makes sense. When I did scenePos() it showed the right coordinates. Thank u.